# I'm attempting to self-join outer join based on dates to return numeric differences - MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, self-join

I'm attempting to self join this table on the ID and Task_ID field, joining yesterday's date with today's date, so that I can return items that have increased or decreased between yesterday and today. I also want to return items that have dropped off from yesterday, or are new as of today. I think I want to do an outer self-join, if that makes sense.

I currently have this query working by joining two temp tables together, one with today's date and one with yesterday's date, and then subtracting yesterday's number from today's number, returning any nulls or non-zero difference values. However, I want to increase my SQL skills, but I keep running into problems with this query. Thank you in advance for your help!

My Data looks like this:

| ID | task_id | number | date_stored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BH1 | 6 | 01/18/2021 |
| 2 | BH1 | 5 | 01/19/2021 |
| 7 | AK9 | 3 | 01/18/2021 |
| 7 | KL8 | 2 | 01/19/2021 |
| 7 | KL8 | 2 | 01/18/2021 |

I tried this, but it (I believe) implicitly assumed an inner join and excluded the dropped and new items:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table t1, table t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id = t2.id 
and 
    t1.task_id = t2.task_id 
and 
    t1.date_stored != t2.date_stored
```

Then I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    T1.*, 
    t2.number as today_no, 
    t1.number - t2.number as diff_btw 
FROM 
    table t1 LEFT JOIN table as t2 
        on t1.ID = t2.ID 
        and t1.task_id = t2.task_id 
        and t1.date_stored <> t2.date_stored 
WHERE 
    t1.date_stored = '2021-01-18' 
and 
    t1.number - t2.number IS NULL 
or 
    t1.number - t2.number <> 0
```

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Comment: You would be better off using `LEAD`/`LAG`. If you're self joining, that would suggest that you don't have access to those functions, meaning you're using SQL Server 2008 or prior; that's been unsupported or ~2.5 years.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give those functions a shot. I think I'm actually on SQL Server 2014 :)

Comment: @Kate rather than adding code in the comments, you should edit your question and add the code there. I've done that for you.

Comment: `FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id ...` is an old-style `INNER JOIN`, which should be avoided. Use `FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id ...` instead.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! That seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

As @Larnu said, use `LAG`:

```
WITH cte As
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        task_id,
        date_stored,
        number As today_no,
        LAG(number) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, task_id ORDER BY date_stored) As yesterday_no
    FROM
        table
)
SELECT
    ID,
    task_id,
    date_stored,
    today_no,
    yesterday_no,
    today_no - yesterday_no As diff_btw
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    yesterday_no Is Null
Or
    today_no != yesterday_no
ORDER BY
    task_id,
    date_stored
;
```

[LAG (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)